# Ensure high availability of Windows Azure website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, high-availability

What would be the proper way to deploy Windows Azure Web sites to ensure maximum availability, even in case of datacenter issues?

I am facing a service outage as I write, due to the ongoing "partial service interruption" affecting websites in West Europe in the last 6 hours.

It is kind of moot to setup redundant database instances (and redundant everything, really) if my web endpoint can die on my customers. I've already verified that increasing instance count does not really improve the robustness of Azure websites in such situations.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are experiencing the same issue at the moment :( We have created another website in EU North and uploaded our site to there. We have then setup automatic DNS failover using [DNSMadeEasy](http://dnsmadeeasy.com). Unfortunately it will take some time for propogation so in the mean time we are just asking our users to visit the temporary URL. This should hopefully mitigate issues like this in the future.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is actually pretty cool. Thanks for sharing! Could you let us know how long did it take for your customers to be redirected to the new address?

Comment: Also, do you have experience in using this service jointly with SSL certificates?

Comment: We only moved over about an hour ago. It is taking a while to kick in, I think it takes around 24 hours to fully propagate. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I do not have experience using it with SSL, but I will let you know how that goes *hold thumbs*

Comment: out of curiosity - are you running on Bizspark credits or paid subscription? I'm not sure if the standard SLA applies for Bizspark...

Comment: It turns out DNSMadeEasy does not support CNAME failover at this point, so this solution will not work. We are a Bizspark member but we removed the limit so are a paid customer. We are going to continue using DNS made easy because they are planning CNAME failover which will hopefully come sooner rather than later.

Comment: I am now taking a look at Route53 to perform some DNS failover. If I understand correctly, it would be possible to perform CNAME failover with it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48668/discussion-between-peuge-and-andrea)

Answer (score 5):

Since this answer was accepted, MS have released Azure traffic manager, which allows you to configure a failover to another instance, running on another region.

More info: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-overview/